# Cannot find element with Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate the 'sort by' button in a Yahoo Finance stock comment page(e.g. [TSLA](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/community?p=TSLA)). However, Selenium fails to find the element with its id even though it exists. I have already switched to iframe and wait enough time for the item to load but it does not work.

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[contains(@id, "jacSandbox")]'))
sortby = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@id="spotim-sort-by"]')
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: I got 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@id="spotim-sort-by"]"}' error. But I searched the element is definitely within the first iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the image below, the button is inside a `shadow-root` which is inside a `iframe`. So, after switching to the `iframe` you have to use javascript to let selenium be able to "see" it.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[contains(@id, "jacSandbox")]'))

# shadow_parent is <div ow-34id5k6u61>
shadow_parent = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#spotim-specific > div > div')
outer = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', shadow_parent)
sortby = outer.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#spotim-sort-by')
```

[image]

Comment: You can't believe how much trouble this little tag gave me. Thanks for the help!